# Update values of all public variables of class using get_object_vars()

Tags: php, class, object, data-members

I have class with 100 public members. How can I update them in an automated way, ie without specifying their name. I have tried this and I'm getting variables but the changes made doesn't reflect on actual object. Please advice.

```
    class foo {
    public $b = 1;
    public $c = 2;


    function __construct()
    {
        $x = get_object_vars($this);
        foreach ($x as $obj) {
                 $obj = 9;
        }
    }
}

$test = new foo;

echo $test->c;
```

It prints vale of 'c' as 2 instead of 9

Comment: Why do you need 100 members in your class? Why do you need to update all of them at once? Maybe it should be an array?

Comment: Actually those 100 variables are already array. I changed them in my question for simplicity. I need to replace some data in them dynamically.

Comment: Then just loop through the array, updating the elements.

Comment: Ya. but I don't want to mention this 100 names...

Comment: What 100 names? Are they an array with 100 elements, or are they 100 different variables?

Comment: 100 different arrays

Comment: Then it probably should be a 2-dimensional array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function __construct()
{
    $x = get_object_vars($this);
    foreach ($x as $key => $value) {
        $this->$key = 9;
    }
}
```